# How to Create a Broken Shortcut in Windows?

Tags: windows, shortcut-file

Suppose there's a file/directory I want to make a shortcut to, but doesn't exist yet. I would anyhow like to make a desktop shortcut to it in advance (a quick testing device for when it does exist). Is it possible?

I right click, trying to create a (broken) shortcut, and I give it the absolute path of what I'm trying to link; however, it notifies me that this path does not exist and refuses to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your cmd (maybe you need administrator permission) and type:

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop (choose a folder to create the shortcut)
mklink linkName targetFolderOrFile
```

Examples:

```
mklink myShortcut C:\GhostFolder
mklink myShortcut C:\FakeFile.exe
mklink myShortcut %userprofile%\Desktop2
```

You can use `mklink /?` for help

Comment: Yep, it unfortunately takes admin privileges that I don't have, but I appreciate the answer! I knew this was something you could do on Linux command line.

Comment: This creates a symbolic link, not a shortcut.  That might be close enough for the OPs purposes, but do be aware that they're not the same thing.